# Creating a multimedia component in Tridion Templating class

Tags: tridion

I am trying to create a multimedia component in Tridion templating classs with the below code.

```cs
MemoryStream stringInMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("
<test>testing</test>"));                            
Component xmlMultimediaComponent = new Component(engine.GetSession(), new 
  TcmUri("tcm:21-2008-2"));                
xmlMultimediaComponent.Title = "New MM component";
xmlMultimediaComponent.Schema = new Schema(new TcmUri("tcm:10-6532-8"), 
 engine.GetSession());                
xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.MultimediaType = new MultimediaType(new 
   TcmUri("tcm:0-36-65544"), engine.GetSession());                                         
xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.MimeType = "application/xml";
xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.FileExtensions = new List<string> 
   {"xml", "XML"};
xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.UploadFromStream = stringInMemoryStream;
xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.Filename = "testing.xml".ToLower();                                    
xmlMultimediaComponent.Save();                
xmlMultimediaComponent.CheckIn(true);
```

Note that "tcm:21-2008-2" is folder TCM ID in which the component has to be created.
The "tcm:10-6532-8" is the Multimedia schema ID and "tcm:0-36-65544" is the multimedia type ID.

However there seems to some issue and it is failing with below error:

> Link to Schema has invalid value.
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Utilities.ThrowInvalidLinkException(Link link, KernelException innerException)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLink(Link link)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLinks(IEnumerable`1 links)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLinks()
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()

The above error is occuring at below statement `xmlMultimediaComponent.Save()`.

Any idea how can we pass LinkToMultimedia type schema id to Multimedia component?

Comment: I wonder what's the use case to _create_ images when publishing...

Comment: For a custom requirement, the need was to create xml multimedia component instead of Image multimedia component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the schema ID must contain the context publication ID, so in this case 10-6532-8 should be 21-6532-8.

Thanks

Comment: Yup, you _always_ have to use the same context.